# Allow computer to sleep even with Mobile Hotspot turned on

Tags: windows, windows-10, wireless-networking, sleep, hotspot

The way it is right now, as long as the hotspot is turned on, the computer will never go to sleep. Enabling the power save option wouldn't change anything as my devices stay connected to the hotspot all the time.

Right now my computer stays on most of the night because when I fall asleep the hotspot keeps the computer awake even though I use neither of them. I don't mind the hotspot function stopping. Of course it would be nice if it resumed when the computer woke up, though I'd be fine with just having the computer be able to sleep.

Is there any hidden setting (in registry for example) to stop Mobile Hotspot from disabling sleep?

Comment: What happens when you suspend the machine  (Right click on Start, Shut down or Sign Out, select Sleep).  Does it suspend?  I set Mobile Hotspot ON, closed my lid, laptop suspended, and then when I opened the lid, Mobile Hotspot was OFF.

Comment: The screen turns off but the computer doesn't go to sleep. Disabling the Mobile Hotspot  and doing the same thing, the computer goes to sleep. I've tried with "Power Saving" turned on in the Hotspot's settings, with or without connected devices, with different power plans.

Comment: Thanks for the update. As I noted above, what you wish to do works fine here. For your particular model, go to the Manufacturer's support website, get BIOS, and then if they have them, Chipset and Power Management Driver. Update all these drivers , restart and see if the updates help.

Comment: I've tried all of that and nothing seems to work. I ended up having to use Connectify, with the added bonus that it's more customizable and the hotspot starts itself back up when the computer wakes up. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

First turn on Wifi Hotspot then open Device Manager:

Select Network Adapters:

1. Double-click on your Wifi adapter (eg: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 160Mhz). Select Power Management tab and check(activate) "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"
2. Double-click on Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter. Select Power Management tab and check(activate) "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

This should let your PC go to sleep even while Hotspot is turned on. It will go to sleep and hotspot will be turned off automatically.